# Should you recite amen after Ahava Rabbah?

Tags: shema, amen

I have seen the practice of people saying the bracha of Ahava Rabbah along with the chazzan, and going straight into Shema without answering amen. I have also seen people answer amen to this bracha.

Are there sources for either of these practices, or which one might be preferable?

Comment: See the Chiddushei HaRamban at the beginning of Berachos

Answer (score 6):

The [**Shulchan Aruch**](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.59.4?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.59.25&lang2=he) 59:4 says *not* to answer amen after Ahava Rabbah/Olam.

The [**Rema**](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.61.3?lang=he&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=he) to 61:3 says that the custom is people finish Ahava Rabbah before the *Shatz*, so they can answer Amen.

The **Mishnah Berurah** 59:4 § 25 (linked above) explains that Ahava Rabbah isn't a regular *birkas hamitzvah*, where you shouldn't speak before doing the *mitzvah*. It sounds like from him that the **Shulchan Aruch** disagrees.

The **Mishnah Berurah** writes that the *Achronim* agree with the **Rema** that you **should** answer amen if you finish before the *shatz*. However, he finishes by writing:

> אך לכתחלה יותר טוב שיסיים בשוה עם הש"ץ ולא יצטרך לענות אמן אחריו

The practice you've observed is based off this **Mishnah Berurah**. He advises to finish along at the same time as the *shatz*, so as to not be obligated to say amen, seemingly to avoid this dispute.

Comment: This is an innovation of the Mishna Berurah for an ashkenazi to be strict for a non ashkenazi position here. Before him longstanding universal ashkenazi practice was always to say amen.

Comment: Notably the suggestion of the Mishna Berurah doesn't actually avoid all dispute, since it's disputed if finishing at the same time as someone else exempts one from saying amen here since it's disputed if an individual says amen after his own blessing here.

Comment: @DoubleAA I do wonder why the Mishnah Berurah suggests satisfying the Shulchan Aruch in this instance, when he doesn't always try to make everyone happy

Comment: The Rosh didn't innovative it?

Comment: It's important to note this discussion only applies to people who fear spacing out while listening to the leader's public presentation of the blessings and are therefore saying along quietly in an undertone. For those fulfilling their obligation with the leader everyone agrees you say amen. For those praying without a minyan, it's a dispute if you say amen to your own blessing, but most say not to. The question here is to which case is this case, where you said it yourself already but are then listening to the leader, more similar to.

Comment: @kouty No, the Rosh innovated saying along with the leader for fear of spacing out, but he was careful to finish the ends of blessings quickly so he could still say amen to the leader's blessings along with everyone else.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I was thinking